# Testcontainers is not able to build Image on the fly when running within a Container itself

Tags: java, docker, maven, testcontainers, podman

I have an Azure CI/CD pipeline building a Java/Kotlin project using Maven. The Azure Agent itself is deployed as a container and spawns new containers for the builds on the fly.

```yaml
container:
  image: registry/buildImageABC:1.2
  env:
    TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE: "host.containers.internal"
```

Inside this container a maven build consisting of multiple lifecycle phases is running. The one I am having troubles with is the `verify` phase, where integration tests are supposed to be running. Before `verify` starts the `.jar` file is available and packaged.

The part of the integration test that fails looks like this:

```java
GenericContainer<ContainerImageClass>(
                ImageFromDockerfile()
                    .withFileFromPath("Dockerfile", Paths.get("Dockerfile"))
                    .withFileFromPath("target/project.jar", Paths.get("target/project.jar"))
            ).withLogConsumer(Slf4jLogConsumer(logger)).waitingFor(Wait.forHealthcheck()).start()
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM baseImage:123
FROM otherBaseImage:456
COPY --from=0 /work /app/work

WORKDIR /app/work
COPY target/*.jar ./

HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=10s --retries=3 --start-period=20s \
  CMD curl -f http://127.0.0.1:8080/ || exit 1
```

When running `mvn clean verify` I'm faced with the following error log:

```
[docker-java-stream-791735816] ERROR c.g.d.a.async.ResultCallbackTemplate - Error during callback
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.execute(ApacheDockerHttpClientImpl.java:195)
        at com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.ZerodepDockerHttpClient.execute(ZerodepDockerHttpClient.java:8)
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.HeadersAddingDockerHttpClient.execute(HeadersAddingDockerHttpClient.java:23)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:228)
        at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
...
```

and

```
[main] ERROR o.t.utility.MountableFile - Error when copying TAR file entry: /__w/3/s/target/project-0.0.1-DEV.tar
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
        at java.base/java.io.PipedInputStream.checkStateForReceive(PipedInputStream.java:260)
        at java.base/java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:226)
        at java.base/java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:261)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:148)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.CountingOutputStream.write(CountingOutputStream.java:62)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream$BufferAtATimeOutputChannel.write(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.writeBlock(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:259)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.maybeFlush(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:169)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.write(FixedLengthBlockOutputStream.java:206)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.write(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:713)
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.transferTo(InputStream.java:783)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:3213)
...
```

I have two intuitions what the problem could be, but no idea how to fix them nicely:

1. the `.jar` Archive is still open when testcontainers tries to transfer it to the mounted socket. However, the `.jar` should be built after `package`, before `verify`.
2. the podman daemon running on the outside of all containers (on the host machine) is not able to resolve the path `/__w/3/s/target/project-0.0.1-DEV.tar` which is only valid inside the build container. However, to my understanding `testcontainers` sends the files to the socket in binary format to create a build context, hence the paths do not need to be present on the host.

Any ideas? Or are some of my intuitions false?